# Pandas not working in python3 but works in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I tried to run pandas in `python3`. But I get the following error.

```
user@client3:~/smith/Python$ python3
Python 3.7.0 (default, Oct  3 2018, 21:22:25) 
[GCC 5.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

So I tried to run from `python`,

```
user@client3:~/smith/Python$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> exit()
```

It works fine here. So I tried to install pandas for `python3` as follows,

```
user@client3:~/smith/Python$ sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pandas is already the newest version (0.17.1-3ubuntu2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-139 linux-headers-4.4.0-139-generic linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
```

It already installed for `python3`. What happened here? Why it doesn't run for python3?

Comment: If you can go into a Python shell and then do `import sys` and then `sys.path`, does `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` appear? I assume you are using Debian or something Debian-based but what specifically? Distro and version.

Comment: I am not sure but I think you need to try `python3 -m pip install pandas` or `pip3 install pandas`

Comment: Please post the outputs of `ls -l /usr/bin/python*`, `which python`, `which python3`. Did you try `pip3 install` instead of `apt install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, check it out.

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Comment: Typically, that requires administrative privileges. I do `sudo -H pip3 install <package>`.